# $\small{\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}} I & {{B^{\frac{1}{2}}}} \\ {{B^{\frac{1}{2}}}} & A \\ \end{array}} \right) \ge 0 \Rightarrow A \ge B}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A, B \in M_n$ be positive definite, and $\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   I & {{B^{\frac{1}{2}}}}  \\
   {{B^{\frac{1}{2}}}} & A  \\
\end{array}} \right) \ge 0$

Why  does  $A \ge B$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition implies that $\mathbf{x}^{\dagger}\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{y}^{\dagger}A\mathbf{y} + \mathbf{x}^{\dagger}B^{\frac{1}{2}}\mathbf{y} + \mathbf{y}^{\dagger}B^{\frac{1}{2}}\mathbf{x} > 0 $ for non-zero $\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}$.

Choosing $\mathbf{x} = -B^{\frac{1}{2}}\mathbf{y}$ then shows us that $A-B$ is positive definite, hence the result.

Comment: Either,can we prove that   $\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   {{B^{ - 1}}} & I  \\
   I & A  \\
\end{array}} \right) \ge 0$?

Comment: Yes, $\begin{pmatrix} B^{-\frac{1}{2}} & 0 \\ 0 & I \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} I & B^{\frac{1}{2}} \\B^{\frac{1}{2}} & A \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} B^{-\frac{1}{2}} & 0 \\ 0 & I \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} B^{-1} & I \\ I & A \end{pmatrix}$, so this is simply a change of coordinates.